# Firebase Firestore Increment FieldValue does not increment

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

so i've read all the documentation everything about increment a counter in a Firestore database.
I have this code

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const db = admin.firestore();
...
db
.collection("settings")
.doc("totalUsers")
.set({
count: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
});
```

And i just doesn't increment the counter at all. No errors no logs no nothing.
In my Firestore i have a collection of `settings` and a document `totalUsers` with a property `count` that is a number type and it equals to 1.

Am I doing something wrong? 
Am I missing anything?
Any help appreciated!

Comment: Handle the promise chain and check for return value/errors.

Comment: It returns nothing and that call is in a try/catch :(

Comment: Can you show the code? Hope you didn't forget to `await` the async call when adding the try-catch.

Comment: I found out, it was the i was setting instead of updating. Supposed to be `.update` instead of `.set`... silly me. Thank you for your help! Your comment actually sparked something in my mind :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone having issues with this, be careful to use the `.update()` method instead `.set()`. Also you need to have a value existing in the firestore that so it has something to increment.

Comment: I have a similar issue and the funny thing is I am using FieldValue increment as a set() operation on an oncreate trigger. But for another function, i am using onwrite trigger and Fieldvalue increment does not work. But in the documentation it says works with set and update

Comment: I had a missing value, so update was trying to increment **nothing**. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 13):

[increment](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/FieldValue.html#.increment) works with both update and set.
For it to actually increment the field you can:

- use [update](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#update), but the documents must exist already
- use [set](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#set) with option `merge: true` or `mergeFields: "something"`, with *something* the name of the field being incremented

Comment: This is the most complete answer.

Comment: Yes, if you don't use the `{ merge: true }` option with `set`, `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(0)` will set your field to zero instead of performing **NO INCREMENT**. This is particularly useful when your incremental value can be a variable with situation that it can be sometimes ZERO.

Comment: for nested fields it's now a requirement to use set with merge true. Update does not work and this is not reflected in the firebase docs

Comment: I just checked and it still works with ```update```, you need to use the dot notation to update nested fields: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using the Admin SDK, you should do as follows:

```
count: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didnt work. I have updated my question as what you have said made sense.

Comment: Where exactly is your code executed? In a Node.js server? In a Cloud Function? How do you initialize the Admin SDK?

Comment: I found out, it was the i was setting instead of updating. Supposed to be `.update` instead of `.set`... silly me. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this: (this is my code and works for me)

```
var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth
                        .instance
                        .currentUser();
DocumentReference query = Firestore.instance
                              .collection("users")
                              .document(firebaseUser.uid);
                                                    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginView()));
 var loginSuccess = wait model.getdata(_inputCuit.text);

 if (loginSuccess) {
     query.updateData({ "queries": FieldValue.increment(1)});
 }
```

The key area is the `.increment()` method